# Android Force Close java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, forceclose

i got this error in the logcat

```
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{App.Biodata/App.Biodata.viewdata}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at App.Biodata.viewdata.onCreate(viewdata.java:42)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-21 11:58:27.275: E/AndroidRuntime(404):  ... 11 more
```

java file:

```
package App.Biodata;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;


public class viewdata extends ListActivity {

private static String link_url = "http://10.0.2.2/biodatawebservice/view.php";

private static final String BIO_NAMA = "nama";
private static final String BIO_ALAMAT = "alamat";
private static final String BIO_TGLLAHIR = "tgl_lahir";
private static final String BIO_JK = "jk";
private static final String BIO_EMAIL = "email";    
private static final String BIO_PHONE = "phone";

JSONArray biodata = null;

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> daftar_biodata = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.viewdata);
    
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);
    
    try {
        biodata = json.getJSONArray("biodata");
        
        for(int i = 0; i < biodata.length(); i++){
            JSONObject bio = biodata.getJSONObject(i);
            
            String nama = bio.getString(BIO_NAMA);
            String alamat = bio.getString(BIO_ALAMAT);
            String tgl_lahir = bio.getString(BIO_TGLLAHIR);
            String jk = bio.getString(BIO_JK);
            String email = bio.getString(BIO_EMAIL);
            String phone = bio.getString(BIO_PHONE);
            
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(BIO_NAMA, nama);
            map.put(BIO_ALAMAT, alamat);
            map.put(BIO_TGLLAHIR, tgl_lahir);
            map.put(BIO_JK, jk);
            map.put(BIO_EMAIL, email);
            map.put(BIO_PHONE, phone);

            daftar_biodata.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.adapter_listview();
}       

private void adapter_listview() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, daftar_biodata,
            R.layout.list_data,
            new String[] {  BIO_NAMA, BIO_ALAMAT, BIO_TGLLAHIR, BIO_JK, BIO_EMAIL, BIO_PHONE}, new int[] {
                    R.id.txtNama, R.id.txtAlamat, R.id.txtTgllahir, R.id.txtJK, R.id.txtEmail,R.id.txtPhone});

    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ListView lv = getListView();


}

}
```

xml file for listactivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

xml for each item:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Nama"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtNama"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#333"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Alamat"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtAlamat"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#333"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Tanggal Lahir"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTgllahir"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#333"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Jenis Kelamin"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtJK"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#333"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Telepon"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#333"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#333"
        android:text=" "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

i cant find what wrong with this app, can someone tell me why this app force closing?
i already read some of answer here tell that it have something wrong with the xml layout file, but still cant find solution

thanks in advance.

### [SOLVED]

thank you very much stackoverflow.com members for helping me out,
the problem is this

> biodata = json.getJSONArray("biodata");

is null, because my php fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json is null` so NPE.You cant get JsonObject from your JsonParser.

```
biodata = json.getJSONArray("biodata");//here json is null.
```

and check your `json = jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);`

AND no use of `ListView lv = getListView();` after setAdapter to listview.

Comment: do you mean this one? JSONArray biodata = null;

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you should learn to read the log, properly. It is more important to detect problem from what the logcat is telling you. So here is how you can do it:

First, enable line numbers on your IDE.
   Second, take a look at how the problem is described in the logcat:

```
     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity componentInfo{App.Biodata/App.Biodata.viewdata}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

So there is a null pointer exception thrown in your viewdata class. This is happening because you try to access a method from a null object.

Third, continue to search the cause of the problem:

```
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   E/AndroidRuntime(404):  at App.Biodata.viewdata.onCreate(viewdata.java:42).
```

So the problem is in your viewdata.java on the line number 42.

Comment: Answers like this one should be more common. Don't tell people what to do, make them learn what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I Think below line have Error.

```
ListView lv = getListView();
```

So please Used Below.

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

lv = getListView();
```

Answer (score 0):

You extend you activity as List-activity and also you try to access XML layout that maker please. so remove your setContentView(R.layout.viewdata);

Thanks

Comment: removed still force closing, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have error here

```
 biodata = json.getJSONArray("biodata");
```

You must put condition

```
if(json!=null)
{
    biodata = json.getJSONArray("biodata");
}
```

Your `jParser.AmbilJson(link_url);` must be failing